# Can't install software through Ubuntu software center

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit. I can't install software through Ubuntu software center. When I try to install , install button shows disabled and I tried `file->install` its also the same.

Comment: Please run sudo apt-get update in a terminal and post any errors

Comment: Ya. i tried that. I din't find any errors.

Comment: Can you install through terminal try sudo apt-get install smplayer this will just install a video player, we only care if it works or not

Comment: @mark when you post a comment, please format code with the `\`` character to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry I did not know I could I thought I just did not have the rep for code in comments.